# Retry request couple times when it fails through async.retry

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, request

I want to retry the request twice if the first request fails. And I'm trying this through `async.retry`.

Here is what I have tried:

```
let apiMethod = async function(callback) {
    response = await postRequest(options);
    return callback(response);
}
async.retry(2, apiMethod, function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    let tempResponse = results;
});
```

Even when there should not be any error, I'm getting `response` as `undefined`. Does anyone have any pointers on how to use `async.retry`? Thanks in advance.